# Pruning elements in an array based on the existence of similar elements in adjacent arrays

Tags: algorithm, list-manipulation

Imagine I have a series of particles floating around in $\mathrm{R}^3$, where, at any given time, particles can pop into and out of existence. Here, for some number of time points, $(t_1, \dots, t_N)$, I generate an unordered list of the positions of each of the particles present in the chamber: $(p_{(k,1)}, p_{(k,2)}, \dots) \in l_k$ s.t. I have a set of lists of particle positions, $(l_1, \dots, l_N) \in L$, each list corresponding to each time point.

I would like to generate a set of pruned lists $(q_1, \dots, q_N) \in Q$, where each $q_i \subseteq l_i$ consists of the set of particle positions in $l_i$ that likely arose from measuring the same particle that

- existed and was measured at $\alpha$ previous time points. If, for example, we set $\alpha = 2$ and we measure a particle at time $t_i$, we would only place that measurement in $q_i$ if a very similar measurement was made at times $t_{(i-1)}$ and $t_{(i-2)}$.
- also existed and was measured for the next $\beta$ time points. If, for example, we set $\beta = 3$ and we measure a particle at time $t_i$, we would only place that measurement in $q_i$ if a very similar measurement was made at times $t_{(i+1)}$, $t_{(i+2)}$, and $t_{(i+3)}$.

If the particles were frozen in place, generating some $q_i \subseteq l_i$ would be a simple matter calculating a few intersections between $l_i$ (using the `Intersection[]` function in *Mathematica*) under the assumption that the probability one particle pops out of existence and another arises in exactly the same place in-between measurements is arbitrarily small. However, here the particles are moving, so we need to "guess" that some measured particle position at time $t_i$ and either times $t_{(i-\delta)}$ or $t_{(i+\delta)}$ (for small enough $\delta$) corresponds to the same particle if the Euclidean distance between the measured positions is below some threshold $\tau$. So if we set $\beta = 2$, we would need to see that the particle only moves a threshold distance $\tau$ from the current time point to the next, and then only moves a distance of at most $\tau$ in the interval between that time point to the one after (i.e., for some time point $t_k$ we require that some $\lvert p_{(k, \dots)} - p_{(k+1, \dots)}\rvert \leq \tau$ and that $\lvert p_{(k+1, \dots)} - p_{(k+2, \dots)}\rvert \leq \tau$).

Said another way:

Let $(l_1, l_2, \dots, l_N) \in L$ be an array of lists. For $\alpha = 1$ and $\beta = 1$, I'd like to remove all elements in each $l_i$ that are not within some threshold Euclidean distance $\tau$ of any element in the previous list, and any element in the next list in the array. If we set $\beta = 2$, I would like to prune away elements where there is no element, $p_j$ in list $l_{(i+1)}$ that is at most a Euclidean distance $\tau$ away, and where there is no element in list $l_{(i+2)}$ that is at most a Euclidean distance $\tau$ away from $p_j$.

Provided a set of lists $(l_1, \dots, l_N) \in L$, and values for $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\tau$, is there an elegant and fast way to generate my pruned lists $(q_1, \dots, q_N) \in Q$ (beyond writing a bunch of `Do` or `For` loops)? I am happy to handle the boundaries of the list, i.e., $l_1$ and $l_N$, in whatever manner is most convenient.

::: Let's generate a simple example :::

Let

```
 l1 = {{87.02,892},{1,2},{65,23},{99,99}};
 l2 = {{666,666},{777,777},{123,432},{876,28},{39,192},{87.01,892}};
 l3 = {{87.0004,892},{8683,12},{7673,777},{7662,2120}};
 l4 = {{40,40},{50,50},{87.002,892.001}};
```

Let $k = 3$, $\alpha = 2$, $\beta = 1$, and $\tau = 0.01$. Looking at list $l_2$, we notice that the only element in $l_3$ that is within a Euclidean distance $\tau$ of an element in $l_2$ is $p_0 = (87.0004, 892)$, displaced to the position $p_{(-1)} = (87.01, 892)$ in $l_2$. We now need to look at $l_1$ and check whether there is an element within a Euclidean distance of $\tau$ of $p_{(-1)} = (87.01, 892)$, and indeed we find that there is some $p_{(-2)} = (87.02, 892)$.

Next, we need to check that there exists some $p_1$ in $l_4$ that is within a Euclidean distance $\tau$ of $p_0$, and indeed we find that $p_1 = (87.002,892.001)$ in $l_4$ satisfies this requirement. Looking through the rest of $l_3$, we find that no other elements satisfy the above set of requirements.  Therefore, we can write $q_3 = (p_0) = ((87.0004, 892))$.

We repeat this procedure to generate a pruned list $q_i$ for each $l_i$, and handle the boundary conditions in whatever manner is easiest.

Please note that if we set $\tau = 0$, we could easily just write

```
q3 = Intersection[l1,l2,l3,l4]
```

To see this, try

```
q3 = Intersection[Round[l1], Round[l2], Round[l3], Round[l4]]
```

As expected, the result is

```
{{87, 892}}
```

If we want to grab the non-rounded value(s) in $l_3$ corresponding to this result, we can use the script

```
q3RealData = Flatten[Table[Nearest[l3, q3[[k]]], {k, 1, Length[q3]}], 1];
```

Which returns

```
{{87.0004,892}}
```

Dealing with $\tau > 0$ in the manner described above in an efficient way (rather than perhaps extending the rounding trick above) is the tricky part of this question.

Comment: If you have control over the generation of the initial array, it seems to me that it would be a lot easier to number the particles rather than repeatedly have to guess which is which. Instead of the $l_i$ one could have $(n_i, r_i)$ pairs with $n_i$ being the list of particle numbers and $r_i$ the list of positions of these particles.

Comment: @OleksandrR. The problem would be very simple if that were possible.  Unfortunately, I have no way of ab initio guessing the particle numbers (particles spontaneously appear and disappear between time points).

Comment: What process produces the initial array? The fact that the individual particles are not conserved is not necessarily a problem. All you would need is for them to be distinguishable, the easiest way to achieve that seemingly being to number them.

Comment: @OleksandrR. The initial array is produced by sampling the state of the physical system at different time intervals.  If I number the particles in one array, I would then need to go to the second array, check for my Euclidean distance constraint, and number the particles accordingly.  I suppose a solution to my problem could be to scan through the arrays and number the particles in this fashion, then to run MemberQ checks to generate the $q_i$.

Comment: I see. So, by "sampling the state of the physical system", you mean that this is experimental data? Sorry, I had assumed it was a simulation.

Comment: @OleksandrR. I apologize for the confusion.  Yes, it's experimental data, and I can't sample in real time.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution.
Please, consider that it needs more checks, with some longer sequence of lists.

Here is the input I considered, changing your examples so to have at least a couple of points in the pruned list.

```
l1 = {{87.02, 892}, {1, 2}, {65, 23}, {99, 99}, {777.02, 777.02}};
l2 = {{666, 666}, {777.01, 777.01}, {123, 432}, {876, 28}, {39, 192}, {87.01, 892}};
l3 = {{87, 892}, {8683, 12}, {777, 777}, {7662, 2120}};
l4 = {{777.01, 777.01}, {40, 40}, {50, 50}, {87.002, 892.001}};
```

First of all I define a distance function to pick all elments up from a list according to the sample and tolerance

```
(* DistanceTest gives a list of True/False according to which elements in the list 
   variable are close to sample with a tolerance *)
DistanceTest[sample_, tolerance_,  list_] := 
Map[Apply[And, 
          {IntervalMemberQ[Interval[sample[[1]] + {-tolerance, tolerance}], #[[1]]], 
           IntervalMemberQ[Interval[sample[[2]] + {-tolerance, tolerance}], #[[2]]]}]&,
    list]
```

then I created the general function

```
PruneLists[listsPositions_List, a_, b_, t_] :=
Module[{q, k, currentlist, sample},
  Table[(* q is the current pruned list *)
        q = Partition[listsPositions[[k]], 1];
        If[k > 1,
           q = Partition[Map[First,Last[Map[
                 Function[{currentlist},
                           If[q =!= {},
                           q = Map[Function[sample, 
         Join[sample, Pick[currentlist, DistanceTest[Last[sample], t, currentlist]]]], q];
         q = DeleteCases[q, {{_, _}}]]],
         Reverse[Take[listsPositions, {Max[k-a, 1], k-1}]]]]], 1]];

         If[k < Length[listsPositions],
            q = Map[First,Last[Map[
                  Function[{currentlist},
                            If[q =!= {},
                               q = Map[Function[sample, 
         Join[sample, Pick[currentlist, DistanceTest[Last[sample], t, currentlist]]]], q];
         q = DeleteCases[q, {{_, _}}]]],
    Take[listsPositions, {k + 1, Min[k + b, Length[listsPositions]]}]]]]],
{k, 1, Length[listsPositions]}]]
```

this is an example:

```
PruneLists[{l1, l2, l3, l4}, 2, 1, 0.01]
```

If you discover any error, let me know.
I'm sure there are other ways to do the same things in a better and more elegant way, but this is what I get today ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Would this be helpful (where t is your threshold):

```
fun[t_] := 
 Intersection[l1, l2, l3, l4, 
  SameTest -> (EuclideanDistance[#1, #2] < t &)]
```